# should I pass function parameters encapsuled in an object or one by one if performance matters in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, performance, function, object, parameters

I'm often finding myself passing around a lot of parameters from function to function. Looks like this:

```
ajaxLiveUpdate : function (bindTo, func, interval, 
                      dyn, el, lib_template, locale, what) {
   // do sth
}
```

While I could see that storing these in an object `specs` would make sense "visually" I'm curious as to the performance implications of creating the object, assinging all the key/val pairs and passing the object around.

**Question:**
If every ms counts, what is the best and most structured way to shuffle around a large number of function parameters?

Thanks!

Comment: you are saying, leave it like it is?

Comment: thanks. Make it answer, so I can check?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think a good optimizer would make this micro-optimization insignificant. Feel free to use whichever suits your coding style and code reading habits better. If you prefer an object, because it's more compact, go ahead and use an object. If you'd rather spell out arguments expressly, then do that.

Answer (score 2):

There may be some performance overhead when creating and passing object instead of just passing arguments, but I doubt this is going to be your application bottleneck. I would go with an object because of code readability.

Tried it in V8 (node.js v0.10.8).

```
console.time(44);
var f = function(a,b,c,d,e) {
    return a+b+c+d+e;
};
var s = 0;
for(var i=0;i<100000000;++i) {
    s += f(i,i*2,i+1,i-1,i*3);
}
console.timeEnd(44);
console.log(s);
```

**~1440ms**

```
console.time(44);
var f = function(x) {
    return x.a+x.b+x.c+x.d+x.e;
};
var s = 0;
for(var i=0;i<100000000;++i) {
    s += f({a:i,b:i*2,c:i+1,d:i-1,e:i*3});
}
console.timeEnd(44);
console.log(s);
```

**~2236ms**

Answer (score 1):

If you pass arguments encapsulated in an object, here is what happens:

In JavaScript, when you are retrieving a value from an object it is the same as you are using the for clause to parse an array. Cause objects in JavaScript are the same as associative arrays. So you will waste your computational time on searching for your values by a key.

Use this option only and only if you have a lot of arguments (5 or more) and it is a nice way to organize them, plus you will gain the ability to pass arguments independent of their rightful placement.